# Jstree, JSON_DATA plugin and special characters

Tags: json, character-encoding, jstree

I have a jstree tree structure on my page, that uses JSON data and AJAX. There are some scandinavian characters (ä and ö), which aren't handled properly.

Jstree gets the JSON structure through a Java servlet filter. The structure is encoded as UTF-8. When I look at the returned JSON structure with firebug, the scandinavian characters are displayed properly. I tried changing the character encoding to ISO 8859-4 just to see if it helps, but it didn't.

I'm not sure which parts of the code are relevant to this problem, but here's some parts.

Initialising the tree:

```
.jstree({   
    "json_data" : {
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : hostUrl+"/json/getAreaTree?treeType=Areas",
            "data" : function (n) {
                    return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };
                }
        }
    },
```

Some of the servlet filter code:

```
protected class GetAreaTreeContext extends ActionContext implements StreamResponseContext{

    private byte[] bytes;

    public GetAreaTreeContext() {
        super("getAreaTree");
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return this.bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean doAction() {
        if (!getWebSessionObject().isValid())
            return false;
        Map<String,Object> p = getParameterMap();
        String type = (String)p.get("treeType");
        String id = (String)p.get("id");
        if(id.equals("1") || id.equals("0") || id.equals("id1") || id.equals("id0")){ //get the tree only if request comes from initial situation (id=0) or the root (id=1)
            try {
                this.bytes = ObjectFactory.getInstance().getDbManager().getAreaFolderTree(type, phone).getBytes();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                this.result = "";
            }
            return bytes.length > 0;
        }else{
            //init the array again so that when empty folders make ajax requests, they dont get the tree
            this.bytes = new byte[0];
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

How do I get jstree JSON_DATA plugin to handle UTF-8 encoded scandinavian characters?

Comment: Mhh... did you try to add ' "contentType": "application/json charset=utf-8" ' in json_data>ajax properties ?

Comment: I tried, didn't do anything..

Comment: Any luck solving this issue? I'm from Brazil and we also have some common special characters such as ç, ã and é.

Comment: Hmm, this happened ages ago, but IIRC it was a string encoding error somewhere else? I could be wrong though..

Answer (score 0):

I ran across precisely this issue today.  Even though I could see `Øst` being returned in the JSON for the data callback when I inspected the node in the (Safari) debugger, it was being rendered as `�st`.  However, [Ricola3D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365265/ricola3d)'s suggestion worked for me.  I added `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8` to the response headers, and the rendering cleaned up immediately.

YMMV: Our server side stack is Clojure+Ring, proxied behind Apache, and the Content-Type header does seem to impact the encoding coming back from the server, from either the Ring or underlying jetty layer.  I'm frankly unsure of whether the adding the content type header changes how the JSON parser in the browser decodes the response body, or changes how the response body gets encoded in the web server.